# Adjust position of Highcharts line graph data points to be between rather than on each tick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Currently, my chart looks like this:
[image]

Currently, each data point is located **on** the tick i.e. at 3pm, 4pm, 5pm etc. However, the data represented are averages over hourly time periods i.e. 3-4pm, 4-5pm etc.

To accurately represent this data, I need the data points to be **between** each tick i.e. around the 3.30pm, 4.30pm etc. marks but I don't want to show the ticks at those positions.

How should I change my code?

```
Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: null,
    spacingTop: 40,
    spacingRight: 55,
    spacingLeft: 30,
    spacingBottom: 10
  },
  title: null,
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '(Hour)',
      align: 'high',
      style: {
        'color': 'white',
        'fontSize': '12px'
      },
      offset: 0,
      x: 42.5,
      y: -8.75
    },
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%H:00'
    },
    min: startTime,
    labels: {
      style: {
        'color': 'white',
        'fontSize': '12px'
      }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: '#494A55',
    lineColor: '#494A55',
    tickWidth: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '(Boxes)',
      align: 'high',
      style: {
        'color': 'white',
        'fontSize': '12px'
      },
      rotation: 0,
      offset: 0,
      y: -20,
      x: -15
    },
    min: 0,
    max: maxY, // Computed variable
    tickInterval: 0.5,
    labels: {
      style: {
        'color': 'white',
        'fontSize': '12px'
      },
      format: '{value:.1f}'
    },
    gridLineColor: '#494A55',
    lineColor: '#494A55'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: startTime, // Computed variable
      pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
    }
  },
  series: chartData,
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  }
});

// Format of chartData
var chartData = [
  {
    name: '',
    color: hexColorCode,
    data: [integers]
  }
];
```

Comment: You want to change y axis labels  ??

Comment: Since you are using `xAxis.type: 'datetime'` this is not possible. This setting means each point will be at that specific time point. What you could do is convert your xAxis type to "category" and then send in the times as hourly blocks (like "3pm").

Comment: If the timestamp is always on the hour and the average is always an hour, why not just add half an hour to each timestamp?